# Why is my React search function not working when I hit backspace?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to create a simple search function that filters through a list of movies obtained from an API.

The filter function works perfectly when I enter letters one after another, but when I hit backspace the function returns an empty array.

In the filter function I've logged the filtered array to the console and it works perfectly, so I'm thinking it must be something to do with how I've set up global state using Redux.

Here's the filter function:

```
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux'
import { setMoviesToDisplay } from "../features/general/generalSlice";

function SearchBar() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const {filter} = useSelector((state) => state.general)
    const {moviesToDisplay} = useSelector((state) => state.general)
    
    const startSearch = (searchTerm) => {
        let filteredList = []
        filteredList = moviesToDisplay.filter(movie => movie.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()))
        dispatch(setMoviesToDisplay(filteredList))
    }
    

  return (
    <div>
        <input
        onInput={(e) => startSearch(e.target.value)} 
        type="text" 
        placeholder={filter === 'all' ? 'Search for movies or TV series'
        : filter === 'movies' ? 'Search for movies'
        : filter === 'tv' ? 'Search for TV series'
        : filter === 'bookmarks' ? 'Search for bookmarked shows'
        : ''
        }>
        </input>
        
    </div>
  )
}

export default SearchBar
```

This is the Dashboard on which the results are shown:

```
import Sidebar from "../components/Sidebar";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { getMovies } from "../features/movies/moviesSlice";
import { reset } from "../features/movies/moviesSlice";
import { setMoviesToDisplay } from "../features/general/generalSlice";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import MovieTile from "../components/MovieTile";
import SearchBar from "../components/SearchBar";


function Dashboard() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const { moviesToDisplay } = useSelector((state) => state.general);
  const { filter } = useSelector((state) => state.general);
  const { movies, isError, message, isSuccess } = useSelector((state) => state.movies);
  


  
  useEffect(() => {
    if(filter === 'all') {
      dispatch(setMoviesToDisplay(movies))
    }
    if(filter === 'movies') {
      dispatch(setMoviesToDisplay(movies.filter((movie) => movie.category === 'Movie')))
    } 
    if(filter === 'tv') {
      dispatch(setMoviesToDisplay(movies.filter((movie) => movie.category === 'TV Series')))
    }
    if(filter === 'bookmarks') {
      let bookmarkedMovies = []
      movies.forEach((movie) => {
        user.bookmarks.forEach((bookmarkedMovie) => {
          if(movie._id === bookmarkedMovie) {
            bookmarkedMovies.push(movie)
          }
        })
      })
      dispatch(setMoviesToDisplay(bookmarkedMovies))
    }
  }, [filter, isSuccess])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!user) {
      navigate("/");
    }
    dispatch(getMovies());


    return () => {
      dispatch(reset());
    };
  }, [user, navigate, isError, message, dispatch]);

  
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Sidebar />
        <SearchBar />
        {filter !== 'bookmarks' ? (
        <> 
        <h2>Trending</h2>
        <ul>
          {moviesToDisplay && moviesToDisplay.map((movie, index) => {
            return movie.isTrending &&
              <MovieTile key={index} movie={movie} />
          }
          )}
        </ul>
        <h2>Recomended for You</h2>
        <ul>
          {moviesToDisplay && moviesToDisplay.map((movie, index) => {
            return !movie.isTrending &&
              <MovieTile key={index} movie={movie} />
          }
          )}
        </ul>
        </>
        ) : (
        <>
        <h2>Bookmarked movies</h2>
        {moviesToDisplay && moviesToDisplay.map((movie, index) => {
          return movie.category === 'Movie' &&
          <MovieTile key={index} movie={movie} />
        }
        )}
        <h2>Bookmarked tv shows</h2>
        {moviesToDisplay && moviesToDisplay.map((movie, index) => {
          return movie.category === 'TV Series' &&
          <MovieTile key={index} movie={movie} />
        }
        )}
        </>  
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Dashboard;
```

And the this is the slice where the setMoviesToDisplay is created:

```
const initialState = {
    filter: 'all',
    moviesToDisplay: []
}

const generalSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'general',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setFilter: (state, action) => {
            state.filter = action.payload
        },
        resetFilter: (state) => {
            state.filter = 'all'
        } ,
        setMoviesToDisplay: (state, action) => {
            state.moviesToDisplay = action.payload
        }
    }
})

export const {setFilter, resetFilter, setMoviesToDisplay} = generalSlice.actions
export default generalSlice.reducer
```

Comment: hmm. so if you overwite the original state `moviesToDisplay` with a filtered version of the same list, how do you expect to get back the original? since now the new value of `moviesToDisplay` is a filtered version of itself.

Comment: The filtering should happen in a memoized selector btw, not somewhere in the component - for both bookmarked and filtered movies.